# OneDrive API: creating and receiving item (embedded) links

Tags: onedrive

1) How do I create an **embedded link** via the **OneDrive API** (https://api.onedrive.com/)? I know that it is possible to create a view or edit link via the following POST call via:

```
POST https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{item-id}/action.createLink
Body: {  "type": "view|edit" }
```

But requesting 'embed' isn't possible, although the [documentation](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/facets/sharinglink_facet.md) shows that it is one of the valid types. I know that it is possible via the Live SDK:

`https://apis.live.net/v5.0/{file-ID}/embed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

But how do I do this for the  **OneDrive API?**

2) Is it possible to receive the already **existing links** via the OneDrive API in another way than via creating a new one via `{file-ID}/action.createLink` call? For example by expanding the metadata?

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{item-id}?expand=***links/permissions***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the same question was asked on the [Github OneDrive forum](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/102). You see their answers below:

> 1. Currently the OneDrive API only supports view and read links. **You can vote to include embed support** via their [User Voice page](http://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/7845657-improve-api-by-extending-the-createlink-method-to).
> 2. In the future, you'll be able to enumerate existing links on an item (at least those links created by your app) to discover existing URLs without the need to call createLink. There is not yet a timeframe for when we'll roll that out, but it should be soon.